# Array state is not updating in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, react-hooks

I am updating a Array state when a socket.on runs and this is my code

```
const myarray = [];

const socket = io.connect("http://localhost:3000");

const [jobData, setJobData] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
  console.log("jobata performed",jobData);
}, [jobData]);

socket.on("job received", (userdata) => {
  console.log(userdata);
  console.log(jobData);
  const newarray = [...jobData,userdata]
  setJobData(newarray);
  // Update the jobData state with a new array reference
});
```

so in this code `socket.on` is running perfectly and userdata is showing new item everytime but the jobdata is not adding new user data and only one element is added. i am using this in my component in map function

```
{jobData.map((item, index) => {
          return (
            <section key={index}>
              <div className=" border-2  border-[#6B84DD] rounded-md p-1 my-4 ">
                <span className="flex items-center justify-between">
                  <div>
                    <span className=" pr-2  font-semibold">Date :</span>
                    <span className="font-medium">{item.date}</span>
                  </div>
                  <div>
                    <span className=" pr-2  font-semibold">Time :</span>
                    <span className="font-medium">{item.time}</span>
                  </div>
                </span>
              </div>
            </section>
          );
        })}
```

so please suggest way to add userData in jobData and update the component with new values

Comment: "but the jobdata is not adding new user data and only one element is added." You start with empty array on jobData so it is adding once. Are you sure socket.on triggers more than once?

Comment: It might be because every time you update the state a brand new socket is being created. What is `myArray`?

Comment: no connection is only made one time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you wrote it may work 99% of the time, but a better way according to React docs is to access the previous state.

Give this a try:

```
setJobData(prevState => [...prevState, userdata]);
```

https://react.dev/reference/react/useState#updating-state-based-on-the-previous-state

Comment: react is weird. btw thanks for the solution.

Comment: can you please explain why my solution not working

Comment: It guarantees that you update the most recent version of state. In other words, it's possible that you were updating a different version of the state and therefore it wasn't accurately setting the state like you'd have expected. 
Your code in theory should work just fine, but Javascript can be tricky at times especially with async functions.